# How can I make a input that goes to a youtube video?

Tags: html, forms, input, youtube

I'm trying to make an input that goes to a youtube video by entering a video ID.  What I'm I doing wrong with this code?

```
<form method="get" action="http://www.youtube.com/embed/">
            <input id="searchinput" type="text" placeholder="Enter Video ID" name="" value="">
            <input type="hidden">
</form>
```

Comment: Are you using any javascript code to "get" the text entered by the user?

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessary use a form like that.
You can use javascript to get value from input and change the page.

```
<head>
     <script>
        function goToYoutube(){
            const id = document.querySelector("#searchinput").value;
            location.href = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + id;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="searchinput" type="text" placeholder="Enter Video ID" name="" value="">
    <button type="button" onclick="goToYoutube()">GO</button>
</body>
```

I don't know if that link is correct, but the code works!